# Merging data frames based on values from two column in R

Tags: merge, where-clause, outer-join

I have 11 data frames that I am trying to merge/join together. I want to join them based on a Id value and a date. Each table has 31 days (a month) per Id value. I would be able to do this in SQL however I don't know the syntax in R very well.

Overall, I want to say something along the lines of OUTER JOIN this table to that table WHERE Id = ... and Date in df1 = Date in df2. And then do that for every table so that I have one huge data frame that I can then export.

I'm pretty new to R so any help would be appreciated - I've seen others asking a similar question however the answers confused me.

Comment: I've just discovered that merge(df1,df2) will recognize common variable automatically! wow!